# What two numbers need to be removed?

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

What two numbers need to be removed?

The first one from the left circle, the second one from the right.

[image]

Comment: Hi Carlo, and welcome to PSE! When posting puzzles that you didn’t create yourself, it’s important to cite the source where the puzzle is from. Happy puzzling!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would remove:

> 4817 from the left and 1387 from the right

because:

> All the rest of the numbers have a 'match' in the other circle which could be obtained by re-shuffling their digits:
>
>  7496 - 9674
>  6279 - 7296
>  2831 - 8132
>  3489 - 4398
>  2614 - 4216

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. I think that its correct answer!